# Print statements from OpenCL Kernel to Android LogCat

Tags: debugging, opencv, opencl

I'd like to be able to check to see if an OpenCV-OpenCL kernel is being called from my Android app and set debug messages inside it. Is there any way I can send these messages to the logcat?

If not, where exactly will the print statements be shown if I just use printf instead?

Comment: There is no easy way. What I can think of is to write a pure NDK program for debug, once it works, add JNI interface and integrate it into your java code. 

OR you can consider to redirect the standard output to some where through pipe. Then you may be able to display it in your Android app. 

The first method is the typically way to debug native code, and it is much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'll give them a try.